# Proof By Induction - Factorials

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\right)\left((n + 1)! = (n + 1) \cdot n!\right)$

Prove the following statement by induction: for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k \cdot k!) = (n + 1)! − 1$

Base case: $n =0$

$(0\cdot 0!) = 0 ~\wedge~ (0+1)! - 1 = 0$, true.

Assume $n$ is true so $k = n+1$
$(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!= (n+1)\cdot(n+1)n!$

I'm not sure where to carry on from here? Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} k{\cdot}k!=\sum_{k=0}^nk{\cdot}k!+(n{+}1){\cdot}(n{+}1)!=(n{+}1)!{-}1+(n{+}1){\cdot}(n{+}1)!=(n{+}2){\cdot}(n{+}1)!{-}1=(n{+}2)!{-}1$$

Comment: why are you adding here: "(n+1)!−1+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!"?

Comment: @ASoni Adding what?

Comment: here (n+1)!−1   "+"  (n+1)⋅(n+1)!

Comment: @ASoni Is it clear now?

Comment: is this by induction?

Comment: @ASoni Please learn what induction is (google, wikipedia). I won't be explaining it to you here.

Comment: Great! Ive understood this! just one question from "(n+1)!−1+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!" did you take out a factor of (n+1)!?

Comment: @ASoni Yes, $(n{+}1)!{-}1{+}(n{+}1){\cdot}(n{+}1)!=(n{+}1)!{+}(n{+}1){\cdot}(n{+}1)!{-}1=(n{+}1)!(1{+}n{+}1){-}1$

Answer (score 0):

> @ASoni Yes,
>   (n+1)!−1+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!=(n+1)!+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!−1=(n+1)!(1+n+1)−1(n+1)!−1+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!=(n+1)!+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!−1=(n+1)!(1+n+1)−1
>   – user2345215 Nov 11 '14 at 22:56

How do you get from `(n+1)!+(n+1)⋅(n+1)!−1` to `(n+1)!⋅(1+n+1)−1` ?

Factoring out `(n+1)!` from `(n+1)!+[(n+1)⋅(n+1)!]−1` you will have `(n+1)!⋅[1+(n+1)]-1`.

Similarly, you may wish to factor a `2` out of only the first two of three terms in `(2+4)-1`. In which case you will have `[2⋅(1+2)]-1`.